# JavaFX 8 Media Player Progress Slider

Tags: java, javafx

So, I have been developing a Media Player application using JavaFX for some time. Unfortunately I have come accross a problem which I don't know how to fix. The slider in my GUI that is supposed to show the video's progress is not working properly. It ends too early. So the video continues until it ends, but the slider has already stopped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Double time = player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds();

    player.currentTimeProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) -> {
        slider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
    });
    slider.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
        player.seek(Duration.seconds(slider.getValue()));
    });
```

Comment: Are you using `slider.setMax()` / able to tell how long the video is before playing?

Comment: No, I am not. Should I get the video's length before playing it?

Comment: Yes, the `Slider` has a default max of `100` which means your slider appears to finish around 1 minute 40 seconds? You would have to calculate how many seconds the video is and then use that to set the slider's max value.

Comment: Yes, but isn't Double time = player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds(); supposed to do that?

Comment: Well, I didn't see it at first but if that's the total length of the video in seconds than yes. You would want to add `slider.setMax(time);` after that line.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I added this to the code, the slider thumb disappeared.

Comment: A Slider's button disappears if the max is less than or equal to the minimum which is 0. Is your `player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds()` returning correctly? Try printing it out to be sure.

Comment: It printed a character. I'm not sure what is wrong, though. I'm using FileChooser to choose a video and play it. It is working.

Comment: What character did it print out? Did you print out `time`? What I think is that `getTotalDuration()` isn't working if it is returning 0 or less.

Comment: It printed "NaN" in the compiler. I dont know what it means.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Duration.html#toSeconds--), `toSeconds()` returns `NaN` if the duration is `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: I found with the above code that the 2 listeners were at odds with each other.  While I was dragging the slider, the video advancing naturally was messing up the drag.  I ended up creating a variable to hold the currentTimeProperty listener.  Then in the mouse clicked event for the slider, I remove the listener from the time property.  In the mouse released listener I changed the location in the video with a call to seek and renabled the listener on the time property.  Much smoother interactions.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`max` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#maxProperty) of the slider to be equal to the total number of seconds of the media you are playing. Note that the [`totalDuration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#totalDurationProperty) of the media won't be known until the media player has read enough information from the media resource. The best approach is to use a binding for this:

```
slider.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds(),
    player.totalDurationProperty()));
```

In some cases, the media resource will not indicate the total duration; in this case it will probably be impossible to link a slider to the current time of the player, unless you have some other mechanism of knowing the total duration.

Comment: Your solution worked. But I had to change maxValueProperty() to maxProperty() for it to work.

Comment: @Matheus Yes, sorry: fixed that.

Comment: I found adding a listener to the totalDurationProperty to be working better for me.
With this answer's approach I received NullPointerExceptions when evaluating the Binding's Callable.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - You are getting a NPE because the MediaPlayer is still loading the video when the above code runs.  Put the code into the MediaPlayer's setOnReady method which is fired once the loading is done.  Everything I am seeing tells me the MediaPlayer has its own thread and does things asynchronously.